# Swi-Prolog - Finding X Based on Definition

Tags: prolog

I am using Swi-Prolog for what I think is a slightly weird use of Prolog. Reason I say that is 'cause I don't know what people use Prolog for normally aside from Watson.

In any case, I am making a prolog program for defining emotions based off what I tell it like:

```
emotion(anxiety,emotion):-
    emotion(anxiety,prime).

emotion(fear,emotion):-
    emotion(anxiety,prime),
    emotion(when,prime),
    emotion(bad,prime).

emotion(horrified,emotion):-
    emotion(surprise,prime),
    (emotion(fear,emotion);emotion(aversion,prime)).
```

The primes are unary so they're not the issue.

I can find emotion(X,Y). which will be everything that I defined with two arguments.

The issue is how can I find words based off the definitions? Could I tell prolog to find all emotions that contained some kind of definition of anxiety? Which would technically be anxiety as an emotion, fear and one of the "horrified" since I made it be definable through either surprise and fear (which entails anxiety) or surprise and aversion.

Is there a command I can use or would I have to program something in order to have prolog produce such a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can find emotion(X,Y).

If you actually enter `?- emotion(X,Y).` you'll get just `false.` as answer.

When you will add some of the facts required by these rules, for instance, `assert(emotion(anxiety,prime)).` you will get `X=anxiety Y=emotion`.

(I think that you should have *distinct* predicates for 'raw data' and categorization.)

Prolog allows inspecting programs, the primary 'reflexive' built in is [clause](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clause/2)/2. On your program:

```
?- clause(emotion(X,Y),Body).
X = anxiety,
Y = emotion,
Body = emotion(anxiety, prime) ;
X = fear,
Y = emotion,
Body = (emotion(anxiety, prime), emotion(when, prime), emotion(bad, prime)) ;
X = horrified,
Y = emotion,
Body = (emotion(surprise, prime), (emotion(fear, emotion);emotion(aversion, prime))).
```

This allows to *meta interpret* programs (see [here](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/acomip/acomip.html) for a clear introduction), and to inspect any detail, after providing the 'navigation' tools. Of course, a statement like `some kind of definition of anxiety` must be detailed: does anxiety occurs as primal, etc etc.

For instance

```
?- [user].
|: occurs(E,emotion(E,_)).
|: occurs(E,(A,B)) :- occurs(E,A);occurs(E,B).
|: occurs(E,(A;B)) :- occurs(E,A);occurs(E,B).
|: % user://1 compiled 0,20 sec, 4 clauses
true.

?- findall(E, (clause(emotion(E,_),B), occurs(anxiety,B)),L).
L = [anxiety, fear].
```

Comment: The reason why emotion(X,Y). came up false was because I didn't include the primes like emotion(anxiety,prime). in the code I posted.
Thanks! Never knew about Body before. But what's the [user] command? Is that some way that allows you to directly modify/append the program or something?

Comment: yes, it's a shorthand for `?- consult(user).`, when I hit ^D (or write `end_of_file.`) the file is consulted.

Comment: Got it. I think that'll be useful later on. Thanks again for the help.